# Conditional operation on two data frames (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I'm having some difficulty executing a conditional operation on two dataframes. For problem illustration, I have three variables: Price, State, and Item, which are stored in a data frame (data1) with those column names.  I use ddply to generate a dataframe (data2) that includes columns State and Item, and the average price(or some other function) for that State/Item combination.

What I then want to do is fill in a column in the originating data frame(i.e. a simple prediction vector), where the column's value is the mean value for a given observations combination of State and Item in data1.  (e.g., if an observation in data1 has **state="Arizona"** and **item="pen"**, I then want to retrieve the average price stored in data2 that corresponds to that state/item combination, and insert it into the column.)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's a good idea to provide a reproducible example illustrating your question. You will usually get a quick answer if you supply enough information and at least a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plyr package comes with a great little function called `join`. You can use this to complete your task.

```
join(dat1,dat2, by=c('State','Item'))
```

Review ?join to see the different types of joins possible. I'm pretty sure you want a `left` join.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to have accomplished what I was looking to do.